# Form Submit Issue

Tags: forms

Below is my form submit statement for my site.  I know that the query works by it self however it does not seem to be setting the variable correctly.  Does anybody see why this would not work, or am I going about this the wrong way?  Basically my module uploads a file and then on submit this function query's the DB for the upload path and needs to set that value to be a drupal variable.  Any Ideas?

```
function background_audio_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
$result = db_query("SELECT uri
                   FROM `file_managed`
                   WHERE `filemime` = 'audio/mpeg'
                   LIMIT 1");

return $result;

variable_set('background_audio_upload_path', $result-->uri);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- You're returning the `$result` variable from the function before calling `variable_set` so that bit of code will never run.
- You have a slight syntax error in your variable set code, `$result-->uri` (you should change it to: `$result->uri`)

This code should work:

```
function background_audio_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $result = db_query("SELECT uri
               FROM `file_managed`
               WHERE `filemime` = 'audio/mpeg'
               LIMIT 1");

  variable_set('background_audio_upload_path', $result->uri);
}
```

The return from a form submit function is never used in Drupal so there's no need to perform the `return` at all.

**EDIT**

Just one other thing, if you're uploading the file in a custom form using a `managed_file` element then you'll have the file ID of the uploaded file available in your submit function. You could then use [`file_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/file_load/7) to get the file object and URI without having to use a custom query. Assuming your element is defined as `$form['audio_file']` the following should work:

```
function background_audio_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $fid = $form_state['values']['audio_file'];

  $file = file_load($fid);

  variable_set('background_audio_upload_path', $file->uri);
}
```